# Add multiple value property to an index with py2neo - Neo4j

Tags: lucene, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to store a multiple value property with py2neo in a Neo4j database.

My code is something like this:

```
names = ["Hello", "Bye"]

batch.add_to_index( neo4j.Node, "NAME", "names", names , mynode )
```

Sadly, checking resulting Lucene index with lukeall and performing searches, it does not seem to work and it seems everything gets stored as a string like: ["Hello", "Bye"]
Would there be any way to properly store it so it can get indexed for all different values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As it says in the docs](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/batches/#py2neo.neo4j.WriteBatch.add_to_index), the `add_to_index` method takes one key and one value as input. So I think you have to add the node to the index twice if you want to index two `names`.

```
# add_to_index(cls, index, key, value, entity)

names = ["Hello", "Bye"]

for n in names:
    batch.add_to_index(neo4j.Node, "NAME", "name", n, mynode)

batch.submit()
```

Comment: That's correct, only single values are supported in this context.

Comment: Thanks. It did work!
Just a side note, you need to keep setting the property as an array:

``batch.set_property( mynode, 'name', names )``